# How to clear Form.List in Ant Design?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm trying to use:

```js
form.setFieldValue(["action", "actions", "1", "conditions"], []);
form.setFieldValue(["action", "actions", "1", "conditions"], undefined);
form.resetFields([["action", "actions", "1", "conditions"]]);
```

The `console.log(form.getFieldsValue(true));` prints object with expected values.
But the render behaves in a strange way.
It leaves two empty husks which are list cards components without any fields.

[image: It leaves two empty husks without fields]

When I check

```
{(fields, {add, remove}) => (
{
 fields.map((field) => {
  console.log(field);
}
}
)}
```

I still see `FormListFieldData` instances there. So I don't really understand what should I do to clear list or some list elements externally.
I also don't use init value on Form.List component.

I tried looking at [example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/priceless-robinson-6q577).

But it gave me nothing. I still don't understand what am I doing wrong.